# C#, how to make list<int> and functional if statements

Tags: c#, list

I am a novice C# user, and I am experimenting with lists in Csharp's console application. This list contains 10 numbers, and the order of these numbers are randomized. What I want to do is to make specific text for a specific number which if statements will handle.

For example: If `number == 0`, the text "Hello" will show up. Or if the `number == 3`, the text "Goodbye" will show up.

I tried a few things but I got problems like repeated text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDCXe.jpg

```
Random r = new Random();
        int tempValue;
        List<int> number = new List<int>();

        number.Add(0);
        number.Add(1);
        number.Add(2);
        number.Add(3);
        number.Add(4);
        number.Add(5);
        number.Add(6);
        number.Add(7);
        number.Add(8);
        number.Add(9);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tempValue = r.Next(0, number.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(number[tempValue]);
            number.RemoveAt(tempValue);   
            Console.ReadLine();   
        }
```

Please help me getting on the right track.

Comment: Maybe a switch statement would be ideal here?

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code.  For example, this code does not show the how you map numbers to text for the WriteLine.

Comment: You could create a `Dictionary` that provides the mappings from integer values to strings.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried and explain why, specifically, it's not working.

Comment: I tried creating if statements, which I placed inside the for loop brackets, under the Console.WriteLine code.

Comment: @John: Then it was as I expected (see the answer below), you should use `if (number[tempValue] == 1)` rather than `if(tempValue == 1)`.

Comment: @John You need to show us the actual code you were using, and explain *specifically* why it's not working.

Comment: @Guffa: Thanks for that recommendation! My code example works just as  I intended now! I'll make sure not to do this error again in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example use a switch to select strings from a value.

If you get repeated values, I suspect that you used `tempValue` to select the string, you have to use `number[tempValue]`:

```
string text = null;
switch (number[tempValue]) {
  case 0: text = "Hello"; break;
  case 1: text = "How do you do"; break;
  case 2: text = "Howdie"; break;
  case 3: text = "Goodbye"; break;
  case 4: text = "Bye"; break;
  case 5: text = "Hello again"; break;
  case 6: text = "Good day"; break;
  case 7: text = "Have fun"; break;
  case 8: text = "Greatings"; break;
  case 9: text = "Goodbye again"; break;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Yes, I did the mistake of not putting tempvalue in brackets. Such a stupid novice mistake. I'll make sure to not make the same error in the future. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not add 10 random numbers to a list and then loop through the list, and print using you if statements

```
    Random r = new Random();
    List<int> nums= new List<int>();

    int numForList = r.Next(0,10);
    bool numInList = true;

    //add 10 random numbers to a list
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       do
       {
           if(!nums.Contains(numForList))
           {
               numInList = false;
               nums.Add(numForList);
           }
           else
           {
                numForList = r.Next(0,10);
           }
       } while (numInList == true);
       numInList = true;
    }
    foreach(var num in nums)
    {
        switch (num) 
        {
          case 0: Console.WriteLine("Hello"); break;
          case 1: Console.WriteLine("How do you do"); break;
          ... //Add more cases here for each possible random number
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because that would not prevent duplicate values in the list.

Comment: @Guffa Fair enough.  I think the user needs to clarify exactly what he wants to do.  I am going off his statement "What I want to do is to make specific text for a specific number which if statements will handle".  He needs to clarify exactly why he thinks duplicates are a "problem".  With no further knowledge, I believe my answer is adequate

Comment: @Kyle: Sorry for my vague clarification. Avoiding duplicates was what I exactly wanted to do. I'll put to mind to be a lot less vague the next time I post a question here.

Comment: @John no worries. I'm new here too. Refer to my edit.  I think that will work